# Pusher.com : Is there a way to use channel.bind_all() where I only get my pushed events?

Tags: pusher

I have a channel that publishes thermostat events.  The events are grouped by temperature changes and thermostat control changes.   I have 3 listeners (web pages): summary, temperature changes and thermostat changes.

I'm thinking I set up a channel 't1' (thermostat 1) and have events such as tc (temp change), tm (thermostat mode change), tsh (temperature set heat), etc.

The temperature change page is easy to set up: subscribe to 't1', bind to 'tc'.

But the thermostat control page is harder. Can I do something like: subscribe to 't1', bind to  NOT 'tc'?  This page wants to receive events on everything except 'tc'.

What I've done is a loop in the webpage javascript to generate multiple 't1'.bind() calls for each event (tm, tsh, tsc, etc.).  t1.bind(tm), t1.bind(tsh), t1.bind(tsc), etc.

And the summary page needs to see all events.   So I wondered about using bind_all().

But if I use bind_all I get a lot of pusher events also.  I guess I can figure out how to filter those out but wondered if you guys have any better ideas.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I figured this out by using multiple channels (which is a feature), with specific events.

Comment: You should copy this as an answer (answer yourself is normal) to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by using multiple channels (which is a feature), with specific events.